# Flutter display video like image

Tags: flutter

I am working on modifying the image_picker plugin for flutter.  I have everything working accept when I return the data back to the flutter app I need help to figure out how to display the video back the user similar to how I would using Image.file for a picture.  Then they can click to upload and when I retrieve need to play it, looked at the video_player plugin, but really only care to have them use the default platform player, but if I can get it to work then the plugin is fine, but no luck so far even seeing the video.  The data returned from the image_picker plugin is a File, I determine that its not a image and go from there.

Any assistance would be great and I can show any code if it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve.Wanted to extend the image_picker to also pick videos? A piece of code or the github url would be a helpful to resolve.

Comment: I will surely upload all the code once done. My purpose is a chat  function in my app where a user can upload a pic or video. Pic is straight forward but a video is not native, so I am trying to display it for the user before they upload and then play when it is retrieved.

Comment: The `image_picker` already picks videos. `ImagePicker.pickVideo` returns a `File` just like `ImagePicker.pickImage`. I'm guessing the original poster wants to be able to do `Image.fromFile(videoFile)`, which doesn't work.

Comment: When I wrote this post, they did not have that functionality in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Good thing that the `image_picker` is picking videos now.

If you'll run the [sample app](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/example) this is how it looks:

[image]

And here is another example where you can play and pause the video that you've uploaded from your local files using the [`image_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and playing it using [`video_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) as recommended in the [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoPlayerApp());

class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoPlayerScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  File videoFile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample Video Player Demo'),
      ),
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
            visible: _controller != null,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                  // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                  return AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                  );
                } else {
                  // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                  // loading spinner.
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: MaterialButton(
              hoverColor: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("Upload Video"),
              onPressed: () {
                getVideo();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _controller == null
          ? null
          : FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
                // correct icon is shown.
                setState(() {
                  // If the video is playing, pause it.
                  if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                    _controller.pause();
                  } else {
                    // If the video is paused, play it.
                    _controller.play();
                  }
                });
              },
              // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
              child: Icon(
                _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
              ),
            ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Future getVideo() async {
    var picker;
    Future<File> _videoFile =
        ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    _videoFile.then((file) async {
      setState(() {
        videoFile = file;
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(videoFile);

        // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
        _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

        // Use the controller to loop the video.
        _controller.setLooping(true);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Actual output:

[image]